# How to handle IO functionally

Tags: scala

I have the following code,I don't want to use var SysProc is there a functional way to do so?

```
   var proc: SysProc = null
    try {
      proc = SysProc(scalaTestCommand).run(ProcessLogger(out.append, out.append))
      forkProcess(proc, Settings.scalaTestTimeout)
    } catch {
      case e: TimeoutException =>
        val msg = "Timeout when running ScalaTest\n" + out.toString()
        logError(msg)
        proc.destroy()
        sys.error(msg)
      case e: Throwable =>
        val msg = "Error occurred while running the ScalaTest command\n" + e.toString + "\n" + out.toString()
        logError(msg)
        proc.destroy()
        throw e
    } finally {
      println(out.toString)
      if (proc != null) {
        println("Exit process: " + proc.exitValue())
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, if your `SysProc` builder throws during construction, var won't be set, so you can already do something like this:

```
try {
  val proc = SysProc(scalaTestCommand).run(ProcessLogger(out.append, out.append))
  try {
    forkProcess(proc, Settings.scalaTestTimeout)
  } finally {
    proc.destroy()
    println("Exit process: " + proc.exitValue())
  }
} catch {
  case e: TimeoutException =>
    val msg = "Timeout when running ScalaTest\n" + out.toString()
    logError(msg)
    sys.error(msg)
  case e: Throwable =>
    val msg = "Error occurred while running the ScalaTest command\n" + e.toString + "\n" + out.toString()
    logError(msg)
    throw e
}
```

and this is already code without vars.

If you want to be even more functional, you can consider something like `cats.effect.Resource` and `cats.effect.IO`:

```
Resource {
  // how to acquire resource
  IO(SysProc(scalaTestCommand).run(ProcessLogger(out.append, out.append)))
} { proc =>
  // how release resource when it is not needed
  // - no matter if it was used successfuly or not
  IO {
    proc.destroy()
    println("Exit process: " + proc.exitValue())
  }
} // defines resource
 .use(forkProcess(_, Settings.scalaTestTimeout)) // create-use-release resource
 .handleErrorWith {
    case e: TimeoutException =>
      val msg = s"Timeout when running ScalaTest\n$out"
      IO(logError(msg)) >> IO(sys.error(msg))
  case e: Throwable =>
      val msg = s"Error occurred while running the ScalaTest command\n$e\n$out"
      IO(logError(msg)) >> IO.raiseError(e)
  } // handle errors if happened
  .unsafeRunSync // run computation (in this case synchronously)
```